# Returning an array of all content types in a folder

Tags: 8, entities

I exported all my configuration files to config/sync.
Now i'm trying to get all the content types from that folder into an array.

Its a bit like what this code does:

```
$manager = \Drupal::entityTypeManager();

$manager->getStorage('node_type')->loadMultiple();
```

But that returns all the Installed content types on my drupal.
I just want the ones from my sync folder because i'm making twig templates from them.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean node types, every node type generates (amongst others) a file called `node.type.NODE_TYPE_MACHINE_NAME.yml` when exporting to config/sync

Answer (score 0):

To know the list of files in your config/sync folder

- Open terminal
- Go to config/sync folder in your site folder `cd config/sync`
- Run a grep command like `ls | grep node.type`